# Rename file with the information available in it

Tags: autohotkey, file-rename

Issue - I have this large batch of pdf, word & notepad files which are required to be renamed according to the text available in each file.
For eg: I have to open file A, search the entire document for the string which will be used as its name, copy, close the file and rename the file.

After searching for some while I found that autohotkey can help me with this though I'm open to every solution. What I want to do is open the file, search for the name, select the text and use the keystroke to close and rename the file.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Any more suggestions or program that can help me achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to give you a script but what you want can be done.

You need to collect various pieces of information when you rename a file. One of them being the current file name which you can often grab from the window title. You can use https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetTitle.htm

If a filename is wrapped in [ ] you can remove those using https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm

If you know the file path (folder where the file resides in) you can now use https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileMove.htm to rename a file and use https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm as a variable.

You would probably like to retain the extension (.doc, .txt, .pdf) so you can use https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SplitPath.htm to grab it and append that to the clipboard when you rename it.

Closing a file depends on your program, sometimes you can send ctrl+w or ctrl+w or you need to use the WinClose command so you need to add in that step before you use FileMove.